# Dimensions of fully connected layer?

Tags: tensorflow

I have output dimension of maximum pooling layer as 16x16x12 which shows that i have 12 images of 16x16 but after fully connected layer output size is 1x1x10. How can i get this size? What is 1x1 is telling?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell with knowing more details of the model. I guess what is happening is that your model is a classifier for 10 classes, and after fully connected layer, the output is reduced to 1x1x10, to be further reduced to a single vector of length 10, as the output of the network.